# apple.com exploit attempt?

Tags: web-browser, exploit, antimalware, browser-extensions

I recently browsed to `apple.com`; and the page crashed a few times, then after I reloaded I was given this alert after my browser attempted to redirect to `res://ieframe.dll/acr_error.htm#apple.com,http://www.apple.com/`:

[image: alert dialogue]

Is this cause for concern, or a false alarm?

`nslookup apple.com` provides

```
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.1.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    apple.com
Addresses:  17.142.160.59
          17.178.96.59
          17.172.224.47
```

Comment: Definitely something to be concerned about. What does "nslookup apple.com" give when ran in the command prompt ? I suspect a rogue DNS server redirected you to a malicious website (and in the long term, something equally concerning is that you're using Internet Explorer as your browser).

Comment: @AndréB. I appended my question with the output you requested. I do have Firefox installed I just keep forgetting to use it.

Comment: Those are Apple's IPs: http://www.tcpiputils.com/browse/ip-address/17.142.160.59

Comment: @MotokoKusanagi the easiest way to remember to use firefox is deleting internet explorer ;)

Comment: @MotokoKusanagi would you be able to make the same request in Firefox and see what happens? It sounds like something malicious is hooking into IE.

Comment: @NicBarker Firefox loads the page without a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is sure that `apple.com` website has been the vector attack. The problem could be coming from any tag, window or web pageyou opened using Interet Explorer.

Given  the warning message you got, I highly suspect your IE browser is vulnerable to a **recent** (July 2015) critical issue  ([Microsoft Security Bulletin MS15-065 - Critical](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/security/ms15-065)) concerning IE versions through 6 to 11. The warning message says a webpage you have visited (not necessarily `apple.com`, as I said) has been attempting to remotely execute arbitrary code on your machine by exploiting vulnerabilities of your IE browser. You need to patch your browser and perform (apparently your AV protected you, but scanning again your machine won't harm you).

Comment: Is there an exploit or POC for ms15-065?

Answer (score 1):

While the alert is alarming, based on the information provided, it does not appear to be of concern.

When IE restarted, it attempted to reopen the page it was last on, which was apple.com. `res://ieframe.dll/...` is how IE reloads the last page it was on. Malware Bytes caught this dll loading and alerted on it.

Comment: SysWOW64 is the backward compatibility module for 32 bit applications running on 64 bit machines, any idea why it would be hooking in here?

Comment: Not really. :/ Without knowing the version of Windows and IE, I can only guess.

Comment: agree! Malware byte did not identify an exploit but a suspicious activity. False positive

Comment: @HexTitan It is IE 11.